# Como remover classes de entidade da Java Persistence mapeadas em um projeto excluído?

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans

As classes de entidade de banco de dados mapeadas em um projeto anterior que foi excluído continuam a aparecer caso eu crie um projeto novo com o mesmo nome. Como resolver com Netbeans 8.2 e Glassfish 4.1 aplicação *Enterprise*?

Answer (score 0):

1. Feche o Netbeans.
2. Acesse a pasta `C:\Users\<seu usuário>\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\var\filehistory` (onde 8.2 é a versão do Netbeans).
3. Apague todas as subpastas.
4. Reabra o Netbeans.

Com isso, você vai limpar a cache do Netbeans e recomeçar ele limpo, apagando qualquer tipo de erro que houvesse na cache.

Comment: Não funcionou acabei reinstalando o Netbeans